# power bi check if date is the last 12 months

Tags: date, filter, powerbi

I have a dataset that has a column with dates in this format: 1 January 2018. the dataset can contain any dates, but what I'm looking for is to add a column using DAX, called isLast12Months, to say 1 if that's the case and 0 if not. I tried working with the dateadd() function, but unless I'm looking at less than 12 months, nothing gets filled in. is there a simple way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a calculated column which flags dates closer in time than 365 days back win 1 and all else with 0:

```
isLast12Months = 
IF(
    [Date] > (TODAY()-365);
    1;
    0
)
```

Comment: hmmm, this sort of works, thank you very much. I'm not looking for the last 12 months from today, but the last 12 months of data. so if my dataset only goes to march 2018, I need apr 2017 to mar 2018. the code then becomes:

isLast12Months = IF(dataset[date] > MAX(dataset[date])-365,1,0)

Comment: Happy my code could help you come up with the solution you needed. Cheers